# Pass Success Message from PHP to HTML page after validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm tiring to Pass a success message after pup checks the database and confirms the data
how do I display a message in case of a wrong password entry ,I tried many solutions with no success ,I tried using ajax solutions and JavaScript with no success as I don't know the basics on ajax and my background in JavaScript is basic
Here's my code

LoginTest.html

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LoginStyle.css">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="login-box">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="http://localhost/Test2/dbloginTest.php" method="post" name="loginform" class="loginform">
            
            <div class="user-box">
                <input type="number" name="civilid" required="">
                <label>Civil ID</label>
            </div>

            <div class="user-box">
                <input type="password" name="password" required="">
                <label>Password</label>
                
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Login">
        </form>
        
        <a href="Registration.html">
            <input type="submit" name="register" Value="Register">
        </a>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

dbloginTest.php

```
   <?php
require 'C:\Windows\System32\vendor\autoload.php';
if (isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && isset( $_POST['civilid'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {

    $civilid = ( $_POST['civilid'] );
    $password = ( $_POST['password'] );
    $hashpass = "";
    $return = array();
    //echo extension_loaded( "mongodb" ) ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
    $con = new MongoDB\Client( 'mongodb+srv://Admin:Pass123@cluster0.ivtq9gb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority' );
    // Select Database
    if ( $con ) {
        $db = $con->VoterDatabase;
        // Select Collection
        $collection = $db->Voters;
        $cursor = $collection->find( array( 'civilid' => $civilid ) );
        foreach ( $cursor as $row ) {
            ob_start();
            echo $row->password;
            $hashpass = ob_get_clean();
        }
        
       
        if ( password_verify($password,$hashpass) ) {
            echo "You Have Successully Logged In";
            header( 'Location:Voters.html' );
            exit;
        } else {
            
            echo "Your Civil ID or Password is Incorrect";
            header( 'Location:LoginTest.html' );
            exit;
        }
    } else {

        die( "Mongo DB not connected" );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could set your *php echo* for the `password_verify` conditional as variable => `$loginStatus = 'true'` and `$loginStatus = 'false'` as a variable, then pass that in your header  => `header( 'Location:Voters.html?$loginStatus' );`, check that on your redirected page and display proper info depending on `$loginStatus`

Comment: @dalelandry how do I display the message in HTML after sending it with PHP as I did what you said in my PHP page

Comment: My above comment should actually be something like `header( 'Location:Voters.html?loginStatus=$loginStatus`, then on the redirected page/s, `$_GET['loginStatus']` will return as a boolean ('true' or 'false'), check its value with a conditional and set the display message there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things here :

### **1- FIRST : DO NOT USE HTML FILES WHEN YOU USE PHP.**

it is more practical and less annoying to go all php even if your code is html only.
so I'd create another file loginTest.php and transfer all loginTest.html contents into it
**

### 2- SECOND : the alert of success

I recommend that you use jQuery along with jQuery UI.
after adding the script links and the UI stylesheet :

- add a div after your form (with the content of your popup) give it an id

```html
<div id="divID" class="mt-5" title="Confirmed addition to the cart">
        <p class="alert alert-info w-50" role="alert">
            <strong>✅ You Have Successully Logged In</strong>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="continue" id="continue-buying" type="button">
            Great !
        </button>
    </div>
```

- in your ajax (you will need to learn it, you can find a [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CXB5y_eJDk)),
  write the following

```js
.done((message)=>{
$('#divId').dialog();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

this shall give you a pop of confirmation.
more here : https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

full ajax would look like this :

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'YOUR DATA'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'YOUR HEADERS'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }).done((message) => {
        $('#divID').dialog();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### **3- THIRD : for the failure messages :**

when you create a php file for your html page, you'd be able to easily manipulate the code to show or not some html parts as the following :

```
<?php if (condition goes here) : ?>
<!--HTML code that appears only if condition is true goes here-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

The ending result of your html page in a php file would look like this :

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LoginStyle.css">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="login-box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post" name="loginform" class="loginform" id="form">

      <div class="user-box">
        <input type="number" name="civilid" required="">
        <label>Civil ID</label>

        <?php if($civilIdCondition == false): ?>
        <p class="alert alert-danger w-50" role="alert">
          <strong>Check CivilId again</strong>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>

      <div class="user-box">
        <input type="password" name="password" required="">
        <label>Password</label>

        <?php if($passwordVerificationCondition == false): ?>
        <p class="alert alert-danger w-50" role="alert">
          <strong>Check password again</strong>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Login">
    </form>

    <a href="Registration.html">
      <input type="submit" name="register" Value="Register">
    </a>

  </div>

  <div id="modal" class="mt-5" title="Confirmed addition to the cart">
    <p class="alert alert-info w-50" role="alert">
      <strong>✅ You Have Successully Logged In</strong>
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="continue" id="continue-buying" type="button">
            Great !
        </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply save all your error and success messages inside a session like so ...

```
$_SESSION['messages'][] = "password is incorrect";
header('location: login.php');
exit;
```

And then display the error message if it has been set like so ...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['messages'])){
echo implode('. ', $_SESSION['messages'])
}
```